# What is the use of '$' sign in String manipulation in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell

This code checks whether the given password is valid according to the constraints in the requirements

```
import Data.Char

strong :: String -> Bool
strong password = all ($ password) requirements
  where requirements = [minLength 15, any isUpper, any isLower, any isDigit] 
        minLength n str = n <= length str
```

Comment: Does it help you if I tell you that `$ password` is the same as `(\f -> f password)`? Maybe you can work it out from there.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner that's a cool shortcut!

Answer (score 15):

```
all ($ password) requirements
  where requirements = [minLength 15, any isUpper, any isLower, any isDigit]
```

By definition of `all`, the above is equivalent to

```
($ password) (minLength 15) &&
($ password) (any isUpper) &&
($ password) (any isLower) &&
($ password) (any isDigit)
```

Now, in Haskell a so-called *section* `(+-*/ x)` stands for `(\y -> y +-*/ x)`, whatever is the operator `+-*/` (which is `$`, in your case). So, we obtain

```
(minLength 15 $ password) &&
(any isUpper $ password) &&
(any isLower $ password) &&
(any isDigit $ password)
```

Finally, the operator `$` is defined like this: `f $ x = f x`, i.e. it is the function application operator. We further simplify the code above as:

```
minLength 15 password &&
any isUpper password &&
any isLower password &&
any isDigit password
```

Answer (score 6):

`$` means "Function Application" .

```
> :t ($) 
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

`$` can be used to provide a parameter to a function. In this case you use it to apply "password" to each function the "requirements" have and have type of:

```
-- because $ is infix, left and right param are the 1st and 2nd respectively
-- partial apply with the right param will still need the left one (a->b)
:t ( $ "a")    
( $ "a") :: ([Char] -> b) -> b --where "b" is a bool in this case
```

seems familiar ?

```
:t (\f -> f "a")
(\f -> f "a") :: ([Char] -> b) -> b
```

`$ password` and `(\f -> f password)` have the same type and same behaviour: take a function and apply it over `a`.

When you have to apply a function over a list, you just put the function alone.
But in this case you have to apply functions from a list to "password". If you omit `$` it will try to do "password (any isLower)" for example, which don't make any sense.

But you can do it using a lambda like `all (\f -> f password) ...` to apply each function to `password` or you can do it with `$`.

Comment: @bunny9131 can you accept my answer as accepted ? or the other one ?